Postgres 15 in AWS RDS WAL disk space consumption > 200GB with Debezium 2.6 with Kafka connectors
we are using Debezium 2.6 with Kafka connectors and has a Spring boot microservice that consume messages from Kafka. We also have 10 databases (Postgres 15) with many schemas per tenant in the same AWS RDS that are being tracked by Debezium connectors. Sometimes  the disk space consumed by WAL files (AWS metric ReplicationSlotDiskUsage and TransactionLogsDiskUsage) increase out of usual proportions, more then 200 GB. We are using one heartbeat per database with interval of one minute. Sometimes some heartbeat stops. We have about 500 tables being tracked by Debezium spread across 10 databases (10 replication slots) with hundreds of schemas. We have more than 2 million inserts and updates per day. We are working with default Debezium topics with a single partition. What could be the problem?

Could be network problems, could be long running transactions, could be subscribers that don't consume the data right away.
